# Giving objects methods to add objects

Tags: javascript, object

I'm trying to create an object that will have a method to add other created objects to it.  For example, I have a neighborhood object that I want to give the method to add a new House to it.  Here's what I have so far:

```
function Neighborhood(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.addHome = new Home();
}
function Home(name, dateCreated) {
    this.name = name;
    this.dateCreated = dateCreated;
}
var shadyOaks = new Neighborhood("Shady Oaks");
shadyOaks.addHome("Smith Residence", 2010);
```

I get the error that object is not a function, so I'm guessing the error is coming from line 3, trying to use a new Constructor as a function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're actually doing above is creating a `Home` instance and attaching it to your `addHome` property.

Instead you want something this:

```
function Neighborhood(name) {
    this.name = name;
}
Neighborhood.prototype.addHome = function(name, date) {
    this.home = new Home(name, date);
}
```